# Inject Blackberry 10 app version number

Tags: jenkins, versioning, blackberry-10

I'm developing a Blackberry 10 app in Momentics that I want to build automatically on Jenkins. I got most of the Jenkins process working, but I would also like it to increment the version number with each successful build.

The version number for the project is set in `bar-descriptor.xml` as `versionNumber`, and displays as "Package Version" in the General tab. In Jenkins, I use "Create a formatted version number" to set Environment Variable Name to `VERSION`, and can successfully echo this in the command line of Build > Execute shell.

How can I inject that version number into my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a regular expression replace inside your text file.

You mentioned "execute shell", so I am assuming you are on Linux. The `sed` command can do regular expression replace.

You could also do it through Ant, or any other tool that supports RegEx.

We can't give you the RegEx unless you show the content of the file that needs to be replaced

**Edit after comments:**
To replace `<versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>` with value of `VERSION` environment variable, execute the following `sed` command with **execute shell** build step:

`sed -i "s/<versionNumber>.*<\//<versionNumber>${VERSION}<\//g" bar-descriptor.xml`

*Note: need to use double quotes in `sed` else variable expansion doesn't happen*

Comment: It is currently running on a Linux box, but the "Execute shell" option is actually a part of Jenkins. There is also an "Invoke Ant" option, which I'm not currently using. As for the file that contains the version number, it's a standard XML file that is generated for BB10 projects. The version number is simply stored as `<versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>` and the build number is stored as `<buildId>1</buildId>`. I may decide to change the automatic increments to `buildId` in the future, but using the `versionNumber` works better for our current versioning pattern.

Comment: This seems to work if I give it a static value, but it isn't taking the variable. The error I'm getting is `[ERROR] MANIFEST.MF: Invalid value '${VERSION}.0.0.1' for attribute 'Package-Version'.`

Comment: Replace single quotes `'` with double quotes `"`. My mistake.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I also discovered that to get it to work in OSX, you need to use `sed -i "" -e` rather than just `sed -i`.